How do I use Amplify when a) we're importing a user pool and b) we have multiple deployments across different regions?
We've connected Amplify to our Github repo. We use Amplify Auth (basically just a Cognito Pool), but we imported the pool from one created with CDK. We have two deployments (one in EU, one in US).
Unfortunately, when you import a user pool, Amplify requires you to commit certain files to the repo itself (at least to my knowledge).
This fact is really messing up our deployments -- it means we need to maintain separate Github branches for our US and EU deployments, when really we would just want them to both be deployed from the same branch.
Anyone have any suggestions?
